# crawling web page through python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, web-crawler, html-parsing

sorry i am new HTML, pleases understand though my question is trivial.

i want to build simple search engine using python.

for that, first, i need to build a crawler to get linked URLs.

and i want to use regular expression to extract linked URLs.

so i did study, but i don't know the exact pattern for link in HTML.

```
from urllib import urlopen
import re

webPage = urlopen('http://web.cs.dartmouth.edu/').read()
linkedPage = re.findall(r'what should be filled in here?', webPage)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are tools specifically for parsing HTML - these are called `HTML Parsers`.

Example, using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://web.cs.dartmouth.edu/'))
for article in soup.select('div.view-content article'):
    print article.text
```

Prints all of the articles on the page:

```
Prof Sean Smith receives best paper of 2014 award
...
Lorenzo Torresani wins the Google Faculty Research Award
...
```

Also see the reasons why using regex for parsing HTML should be avoided:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: So if i want to extract linked URLs in the webpage using BeautifulSoup, how can i use it ?